# Samba share file size error with Windows 8.1

Tags: partitioning, windows-8, samba

I'm setting up a sort of NAS using a beaglebone black with ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
I want to share the storage on an external USB drive and the internal memory via samba.
I think I've configured everything correctly, since both my Windows and Xubuntu PCs and even my Android devices see, read, and write to the shared folders. However, I'm experiencing some difficulties on Windows 8.1.

While all the other devices can transfer big files to/from the beaglebone, with Windows 8.1 all files bigger than 1GB (approximately) can't be transferred. I get an error message saying I need 300MB more storage, but my HDD is almost totally free. I tried with a different file system but the only difference in the results is the size the error message reports (334 or 333 MB on EXT3 and over 1GB on EXT4, both using a 1.09GB file).

This happens only on writing, when Windows needs to read it's all OK.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the `write cache size`, in in `/etc/smb.conf` file.

Comment: I tried increasing the 'write cache size' on the share definition of my external HDD, as you suggested, firs at 512KB and than at 2GB, restarting the service 'smbd' but nothing is changed; the same on my internal memory.

Comment: Could it be a RAM related problem? This device has only 1 GB of RAM and I don't have a swap partition.